# Terraform doubts about resources/data sources

Tags: terraform

I am trying to understand how data are retrieved from Terraform.

I have such a block in the output.tf file:

```
output "id_instance" {
description = "Tell me the instance ID"
value = aws_instance.id
}
```

It is not a type of 'data source' as I see so I remove data at the beginning. It is a type of the 'resource'. The same for name arguemnt.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance

```
terraform apply

Error: Reference to undeclared resource

on output.tf line 23, in output "id_instance":
23: value = aws_instance.id

A managed resource "aws_instance" "id" has not been declared in the root module.
```

But when I type another block as `data` it works and prints some output:

```
output "zones" {
  description = "Tell me the zone"
  value       = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
}
```

So my question is, because as I see both `name` and `id` parameters in the documentation for the aws_instance: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance what am I doing wrong that I see above error? I would like to print the output for them and other, and understand how to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have omitted the name of the resource when you wrote a reference to it.

The syntax for referring to the object representing a managed resource (a `resource` block) is `resource_type.resource_name`. If you have a `resource "aws_instance" "example"` block then a reference to it would be `aws_instance.example`.

`aws_instance.example` would be an object with the attributes shown in the documentation, so it would be valid to write `aws_instance.example.id` to access the `id` attribute of that object.

If you write just `aws_instance.id` then Terraform thinks you are trying to access a resource of type `aws_instance` whose name is `id`, as would be declared by a `resource "aws_instance" "id"` block. You can declare a resource with that name if you like, but your module does not have a resource with that name and so Terraform returned this error.

Comment: Not sure if I understand.

Based on your comment I updated the above block by adding `data "aws_instance" "example" {}` in maint.tf file, then I call again the 'id' like that `value = aws_instance.example.id` and it gets error ... ` Did you mean the data resource data.aws_instance.example?`. In fact when I added 'data' in the above 'value' it works. According to the documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance 'aws_instance" is a 'resource' not 'data'.

Comment: Ok, I see. I call for `data` in main.tf, not resource. when I change block for `resource` then I can call for resource in output..tf. Thanks.